# React value returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

I'm trying to get a specific value back from my input field in my react component but it's returning undefined, I have tried using the useref alone but it's given me the same result( returns undefined, see picture below. I need to get the player names to that I can use their unique ID's as part of an API call that does not list all players, but I do have a JSON file that contains both, so if I can get their names from the input that I have created I can get their Id's and add that to the API to do an API call. can anyone assist me with this?
Thanks!

```jsx
import React from "react";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import "../playercompare.css";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import FormControl from "react-bootstrap/FormControl";
import axios from "axios";
import "chart.js/auto";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import getPlayerId from "../Players.js";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import players from "../Players.js";

const Playercompare = () => {
  // let axiosurl= 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/' +id;
  const playerOneInput = useRef(null);
  const playerTwoInput = useRef(null);
  const [playerOneName, setPlayerOneName] = useState("Choose player name");
  const [playerTwoName, setPlayerTwoName] = useState("Choose player name");

  function playerOneId() {
    let playerOne = setPlayerOneName(playerOneInput.current.textValue);
    console.log(playerOne);
    console.log(players);
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      if (playerOneInput.current.value == players[i].name) {
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Row className="player-compare-row">
      <Col className="col-12 col-lg-4 input-container" id="input">
        <InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-4 input" ref={playerOneInput}>
          <FormControl
            placeholder={playerOneName}
            aria-label="Player Name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </InputGroup>
        <div className="button col-3" onClick={playerOneId}>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </Col>

      <Col className="col-12 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4  input-container">
        <InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-4 input" ref={playerTwoInput}>
          <FormControl
            placeholder={playerTwoName}
            aria-label="Player Name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </InputGroup>
        <div className=""></div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Playercompare;
```

Comment: Code is much more readable when it doesn't have masses of empty lines

Comment: `undefined` is the default return value for a function that doesn't actually return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Bootstrap's form controls work just like any regular `<input>` and can be [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). You don't need to use refs, just states

```jsx
const [playerOneName, setPlayerOneName] = useState("");

// ...

<InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-4 input">
  <FormControl
    placeholder="Choose player name"
    aria-label="Player Name"
    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
    value={playerOneName}
    onChange={e => setPlayerOneName(e.target.value)}
  />
</InputGroup>
```

The `<FormControl>` is now a controlled component which means its value is driven from state and it uses the *change* event to update that state.

You can now simply refer to `playerOneName`, etc in any button event handlers or effect hooks.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log("You clicked the button");
  console.log("playerOneName:", playerOneName, "playerTwoName:", playerTwoName);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("player name state changed");
  console.log("playerOneName:", playerOneName, "playerTwoName:", playerTwoName);
}, [ playerOneName, playerTwoName ]); // run effect when these change
```

Here's a super simple demo showing the controlled component

[image: Edit xenodochial-panini-s7oyym]

Comment: I'd argue for using an object for state: `setPlayer({ [id]: value })` too so there aren't lots of states, and separate functions that have to deal with each input. And maybe event delegation too.

Comment: @Andy I and the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) disagree with you. I have no idea where event delegation would come into this

Comment: Ha :). Ok, so it depends on how you like to group your data I suppose. That React doc is how to manage different distinct types of things (age, fruit etc) This is about storing data about one type of thing - "player" where each player has a different id and value. I just think an object would be easier to manage. And having one event listener on the form is nicer way to approach the problem IME that having listeners on all the inputs.

Comment: @Andy I don't really know what you're talking about. OP has two player names, that's it. No `id`, no objects, just strings. And I'm pretty sure React's controlled components don't work with event delegation. The `onChange` event handler is not the same as the native _change_ event

Comment: Worked well, thanks @Phil :)